# how many Windows 7 I can install with one key obtained from Bizspark

Tags: windows-7, license-key

Am only a newbie to Bizspark. I was able to download Windows 7 ultimate from Bizspark using MSDN subscription. From there I can get keys for windows 7 too. I can claim upto 2 keys from Bizspark membership. But my confusion is in how many machines (PCs) I can install windows 7 with one key. Or 1 key is for 1 machine. So I require 4 keys for 4 machines?

Thanks

Comment: @EricF So I need to get a second key for second computer.. right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these aren't VLK keys or similar, per licensing you can only install Windows to one computer at a time. It doesn't matter where the keys came from, the licensing still remains the same. Read the licensing that came with, this will verify for you how many computers can have it installed.

Comment: You really need to read the license agreement that came with the software.   There are some Windows licenses that allow you to install a single license key on multiple machine (I've seen up to 3).

Comment: **YES**; Please follow heavyd's advice.  The license will tell you exactly how many computers you can activate it on.  It will also indicate if you can uninstall the license from `Device A` and install it and activate it on `Device C`.